# Finding minimum value of a trigonometric expression

Tags: combinatorics

If $A+B+C=\pi$ then what is the minimal value of 
$$\tan^{2}A/2+\tan^{2}B/2+\tan^{2}C/2$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JensensInequality.html. It can be made arbitrarily large by making $A\to\pi$

Answer (score 1):

As $x \mapsto \tan^2(x/2)$ is convex, by Jensen's inequality we get
$$\tan^2(A/2)+\tan^2(B/2)+\tan^2(C/2) \ge 3\tan^2\frac{\pi}6=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Here $A,B,C$ are the angles of a $\triangle.$ So Here $$\displaystyle 0<\frac{A}{2},\frac{B}{2},\frac{C}{2}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$.

Now Using $\bf{A.M\geq G.M}\;,$ We Get

So we get  $$\displaystyle \frac{\tan^2 \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\tan^2 \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)}{2}\geq \sqrt{\tan^2 \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cdot \tan^2 \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)} = \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cdot \tan \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\color{red}\checkmark$$

Similarly $$\displaystyle \frac{\tan^2 \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)}{2}\geq \sqrt{\tan^2 \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cdot \tan^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)} = \tan \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cdot \tan \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\color{red}\checkmark$$

Similarly $$\displaystyle \frac{\tan^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)+\tan^2 \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)}{2}\geq \sqrt{\tan^2 \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cdot \tan^2 \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)} = \tan \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cdot \tan \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\color{red}\checkmark$$

Now Add all Three, We Get

$$\displaystyle \tan^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\geq \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\color{blue}\checkmark\color{blue}\checkmark$$

Now Here $$\displaystyle \frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}=\frac{C}{2}\Rightarrow \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}\right)=\tan \frac{C}{2}$$

So We Get $$\displaystyle \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)+\tan\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cdot \tan\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=1$$

Put into $\color{blue}\checkmark\color{blue}\checkmark\;,$ We Get

$$\displaystyle \tan^2\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\tan^2\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\geq 1$$

Comment: That the _exact same answer_ provides a solution to two different questions is an indication that one should probably be closed as a duplicate of the other.